# How to make product block for full height in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox, opencart2.x

How to make this code to be in full height (cms is OpenCart 2.1 and is using Bootstrap 3)?

```
<div class="row equal">
    <div class="product-layout product-grid col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="product-thumb">
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="caption"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.row .equal {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.equal > [class*='col-'] {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.equal > [class*='col-'] > * {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

CSS doesnt make it full height

Currentl looks like this[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just find answear

CSS

```
.row .equal {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.equal > [class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
}

.equal > [class*='col-'] > * {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).